# Runtime Error 3011 in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I just try to import a .csv file with vba.
I use the DoCmd.TransferText method with custom specs. I tried to import the file with the wizard, with the same specs and it works perfectly fine.

But when I start the vba I get this error Message:

[Sorry, it is in german, but I think one can read the essentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSRgJ.png)

Here is the part of my code, where I call up the method:

```
Public Function ImportFileToTable(params As ImportFileToTableParams) As ImportFileToTableResult
    'TODO: Import a CSV File into the selected table
    Dim result As New ImportFileToTableResult

    On Error GoTo ImportFail
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, params.SpecificationName, params.TableName, params.FileName, params.HasFieldNames

    result.Success = True
    Set ImportFileToTable = result
    Exit Function

ImportFail:
    result.Success = False
    result.ErrorMessage = "There was an error importing the File"
    Set ImportFileToTable = result
End Function
```

My Database is on a Network-Drive, but I tried to copy it on my local drive and it had the same otcome. I also experimented with the File Location.

The Software I am using is:
    -Microsoft Access 2013

Thank you all in adnvance :)

Comment: Looks like your `Params.FileName` doesn't include the full path to the CSV file.

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but I tried to write it directly into the method as well and got the same Error

Comment: Can you `Debug.Print Params.FileName` and give me the result? The problem should be there, don't know any other way to throw that error. Also, try omitting as many parameters as possible to debug, such as `Params.SpecificationName` and `Params.HasFieldNames`

Comment: Same Result when putting it like this:
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , params.TableName, params.FileName | 

Debug.Print Params.FilenName:
        C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\aaaviezev01.bgtvie.jc.local-Cl-201706050505.csv *

*The a's are for blurring out information

Comment: There are hidden characters in your filename (if you just copy-pasted it). Copy-pasting it to the immediate window returns aaaviezev01.bgtvie.jc.local-Cl-20170605??0505. Weirdly, windows does accept renaming a file to that name (as far as I know, it shouldn't). Rename the file first, and then import it.

Comment: I select the file over a file dialog, I will try renaming it and state the result later

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you alot :)

Comment: I was having this issue and it was not due to ASCII characters. It was because the code was moving faster than the backend. I had to put `DBEngine.Idle dbRefreshCache` to give the backend a second to catch up before I could do the import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more full answer:

The filename contained non-ASCII characters. Multiple Access functions can't handle this properly. The solution is to rename any file with non-ASCII characters to something that doesn't include these characters.

Some useful helper functions:

Test if a string contains non-ASCII characters and return true if it does, false if it doesn't (can be used to throw descriptive errors in this case).

```
Public Function StringContainsNonASCII(str As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    'Default is false
    StringContainsNonASCII = False
    'Remove question marks
    str = Replace(str, "?", "")
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        'Search for question marks
        If Asc(Mid(str, i, 1)) = 63 Then
            StringContainsNonASCII = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Strip non-ASCII characters from a string

```
Public Function RemoveNonASCII(str As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        'Append the question marks
        If Mid(str, i, 1) = "?" Then
            RemoveNonASCII = RemoveNonASCII & "?"
        End If
        'Append anything that isn't a questionmark
        If Asc(Mid(str, i, 1)) <> 63 Then
            RemoveNonASCII = RemoveNonASCII & Chr(Asc(Mid(str, i, 1)))
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: I had the same error, but my filename contained no non-ascii characters... But it actually contained two dots (like `import.tmp.csv`). Removing the first dot (`import.csv`) made it works!