# MS ACCESS replacing wildcard and underscore always stopped working

Tags: ms-access

case:
i need to change the barcode if it contains `_A`, `_B`, `_C` into `""`.
for example.

`image_a` into `image`
, `build_b` into `build`

everytime I query

```
update table set barcode = replace(barcode,"\_*", "")
```

then it crashes.

an update:

the problem more like if the query contains `replace` function or `instr` stopped working. no debug option and simply restarting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *How* does it crash? And do you get a specific error, or anything in the Event Viewer, or etc.?

Comment: no specific error, it just simply "access stopped working.."

Comment: so far my assumption that access can't handle special characters such as _ in replace function. not sure tho.

Comment: The `Replace` function doesn't take patterns or wildcards, they just do nothing. This is no explanation for the crash, however.

Comment: i see, i've tried only "_" without wild card in condition and still no luck. I think i have to try other way such as instr and mid

Comment: If you're having unexpected crashes, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40897483/7296893) provides a walkthrough on how to troubleshoot them. Personally, I think weird characters in the string might cause the issue. Check the `ContainsNonAscii` function I shared in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44926401/7296893) (use `SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE ContainsNonAscii(barcode)` after adding that function to a module. If that returns records, they contain special characters)

Answer (score 0):

Try being a bit selective:

```
update 
    table 
set 
    barcode = left(barcode, instr(barcode, "_") - 1)
where
    barcode like "*_*"
```

Comment: The OP wants to remove `_?` anywhere, not just at the start. This will produce wrong results in any case where it does not occur at the beginning of the string.

Comment: it runs, access still working, but the result not as expected.

Comment: stil stopped working, i think this access has something with instr. I tried to remove the instr so it became only left(barcode,4)  and the access working just fine.

Comment: My SQL runs fine here - and it should - so your installation may be hosed somehow.

Comment: hmm, maybe. would u like to see the data sample?

Comment: Yes please. If it can reveal something.

Answer (score 0):

a better way would be using mid function

```
mid([barcode],1,instr([barcode],"_")-1)
```

and you should always have a where condition when updating: in your case something like `WHERE [barcode] Like "*_*"`

Comment: That throws an error for any string that doesn't contain `_`. Combine it with Gustav's answer, and two incomplete answers will make one complete one.

Comment: no one updates the table without a where condition. I assumed checking wherther "_" present would go to the where condition!. in this case mid foundtion without IF() would work faster! :) :) @ErikvonAsmuth

Comment: Well, the query OP provides doesn't have a `WHERE`. Even if it's obvious to you, it might not be for him

Comment: First I have tried Gustav, but we know the result not as expected. then I saw krish answer and i combine those 2. And you know what, access stopped working! god.. why???

Comment: @Anthony time to throw your pc out of the window. kidding :) Typical IT person would say, please restart your PC :D

Comment: haha.. in this situation even something like that worth to try lol.